# Given A unitary, real matrix, all A's eigenvalues are real. [Prove/Disprove]

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I was given the following question from my lecturer, and I can't figure the way of thinking to solve it.

> Let matrix $A$ be **real** and **unitary**. Prove or disprove that all of $A$'s eigenvalues are real.

---

I've tried taking several unitary matrices and check their eigenvalues, but unfortunately, all I got was real numbers.
It does make sense that all A's eigenvalues are real numbers, but I can't get to prove it.

I tried proof by contradiction, but it got me nowhere.
Direct proof seems uneasy, because I can't get to any of A's eigenvalues from the fact that A is unitary.

Can anyone please guide me the way of thinking to solve this question? Maybe I should stick to proof by contradiction until I find anything helpful?
Or perhaps I can't even prove this saying, and there's a special unitary REAL matrix that contradicts.

Big thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered a $2\times 2$ rotation matrix?

Comment: Try to find a real, unitary matrix that is not diagonalizable (over $\mathbb R$). For example a rotation of the plane that has no real eigenvalues because no vector is mapped to a multiple of itself (except for zero of cause)...

Comment: Isn't a real unitary matrix just an orthogonal matrix?

Comment: A real orthogonal matrix with a real spectrum must be symmetric.

Comment: @podiki Thank you. In today's lecture we learnt everything about the rotation matrix. I guess the lecturer didn't expect us to solve this question immediately.